# Spring boot POST Request Validation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, jackson-databind

I have a class called Credentials with two string member variables: username and password

I have another class called Profile. Profile has a bunch of member variables, including two Credentials objects.

```
public class Profile {

    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String id;
    
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String businessAlias;
    
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String localParty;
    ...
    private PartyCredentials localPartyCredentials ;
    private PartyCredentials remotePartyCredentials;

}
```

During POST mapping, the post body Json may or may not contain localPartyCredentials and remotePartyCredentials. Should they contain either, I want to make sure that the "localPartyCredentials" or "remotePartyCredentials" contain both "username" and "password" keys, otherwise it's an invalid request.

eg: This is Valid

```
"localPartyCredentials":{
    "username":"one",
    "password": two
}
```

It's also a valid request if the "localPartyCredentials" JsonNode does not exist. But invalid if either "username" or "password" or both are missing.

Adding @NotNull and @NotEmpty to username and password in PartyCredentials does not seem to work. Here's what my mapping looks like for a post req:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(
            @NotNull @Valid @RequestBody Profile profile) throws JsonProcessingException {
```

Here's what my setters look like in Profile for Credentials objects:

```
public void setLocalPartyCredentials(PartyCredentials localPartyCredentials) {
        this.localPartyCredentials = localPartyCredentials;
    }
```

Comment: You would need to write your own custom validation annotation for this.

Comment: You need to add `@Valid` to the `localPartyCredentials` property also to recursively validate it.